# Is it possible to check login failure with this systax or i need to use expect?

Tags: linux

```
{ echo "username"; echo "password"; sleep 1; } | telnet 10.1.1.1
```

can i chack login failures with this or i need to use expect.I tried to use wrong password and username but i get 0 exit status.

Comment: telnet? seriously? why not ssh?

Comment: You'll just send `'username'` string and then `'password'` string to your host's default telnet port. Why do this? Is it a wizardy? I guess no server will understand it unless a specific listening daemon exists on it.

Comment: I dono much about what you are talking i just copied and pasted it from google and it works but i always get exit status 0 wrong login or right

Answer (score 0):

Since you already tried, you know that you can't check login failures with what you had.
But if you wait longer and know what the host displays in case of a login failure, this "poor man's expect" might work:

```
(echo username; sleep 1; echo password; sleep 4)|telnet 10.1.1.1|grep 'Login incorrect'
```

Comment: maybe with ` telnet ... 2>&1 | grep ...` syntax in order to drive errors from telnet through grep's pipeline.